# WCF Service unable to call from .NET Core

Tags: wcf, .net-core, .net-4.0

I am doing something wrong and I can't figure it out ... I made .NET Framework 4 console application to communicate with SOAP Service, with use of Topshelf I deployed service on a server and with simple URL access to a method or use of Boomerang tool, I can see service is returning value

URL: http://35.231.17.237:8066/ERPCommunicationService/OriginalService/IsServiceHealthy

But now, when I try to access same service, from .NET Core project, I keep getting error:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 
     The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(
      SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(
      String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.
      <CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Code is simple, I successfully used service endpoint to connect it to .NET Core project, where I can see `Reference.cs` autogenerated file and all methods from service are there ...

Here is service call from client side (.net core):

```
public async Task<bool> IsServiceHealthy()
{
   try
   {

      string servicesUrl = $"{_iConfiguration["servicesUrl"]}/IsServiceHealthy";


      //My binding setup, since ASP.NET Core apps don't use a web.config file
      var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
      binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
      binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;
      binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 180);
      binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 180);


      var rsExec = new OriginalService.OriginalServiceClient(binding, 
                                        new EndpointAddress(servicesUrl));

      var clientFactory = rsExec.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
      var response = await clientFactory.IsServiceHealthyAsync();

      return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logging.LogError(ex.ToString());
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And code from server side (.NET Framework 4):

Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/IsServiceHealthy")]
    bool IsServiceHealthy();
```

Implementation:

```
public bool IsServiceHealthy()
{
    bool serviceResult = false;

    byte[] test = new byte[200];
    var client = new ChannelFactory<BisWebWS.BisWebWSSOAPPortType>("BisWebWSSOAPPort")
    .CreateChannel();

    BisWebWS.tauthStrct auth = ServisBasic.GetAuth();

    try
    {
        var result = client.wsTest(new BisWebWS.wsTestRequest(test));

        serviceResult = result.wsTestResult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
    }

    return serviceResult;
}
```

When ever I google shown error, everywhere it says its server side setup, but I am kinda stuck as I installed everything there is ... I am using MS Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter,

Thank you for shared idea how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

The way that we call the service by using the proxy class is an Http Post request, while there is a GET decoration on the method. It requires an Http Get request instead of Post request. This might directly cause the issue.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/IsServiceHealthy")]
    bool IsServiceHealthy();
```

If the server host the service by using Webhttpbinding, we could directly get the result by typing the service address in the browser address bar since the default request is an Http Get request (your link is not available).
This kind of service is called Restful-style service. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design
The typical call is to construct an HTTP request with a request body by using HttpClient library.
We could also call the service by using the client proxy class, like what you do. However, we should keep the binding configuration consistent between the server and the client.
[WCF: There was no endpoint listening at, that could accept the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018130/wcf-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-that-could-accept-the-message/54068160#54068160)
It is too complex to call the service by using client proxy class, it is better to send Http request with HttpClient when we call Restful style service.
Besides, we could also host the service by using BasicHttpBinding, this may simplify the call. There is no need to add webhttpendpoint behavior and no need to add additional **[Webget]** decorations.
Simply speaking, we should maintain the binding consistent between the server and the client when using client proxy.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thank you for answer, as soon as we test it out, I'll let you know if it worked and mark it as accepted answer. thank you once again!