# Nothing happens after adding service to Wcf Test Client

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I added the service to the `WCF Test Client` app and I get *Service Added Successfully*, but I don't see any of the operations available.

This `WCF` service is already being consumed by several javascript charts, so I should be able to see something here.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: WCF Test Client only works if there is a correct WSDL.  That's not always the case with other clients.  Perhaps there is something wrong with the WSDL?  Are the JS clients using the WSDL or did they bypass it?

Comment: Is this SOAP or REST?

Comment: REST. It returns JSON.

Comment: What do you get if you attempt to view WSDL in browser?  e.g. `http://localhost/myservice.svc?wsdl`

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCFTestclient doesn’t support call the Restful service by using a client proxy. WCF creates the Restful style service with WebHttpbinding. thereby the client proxy class generates nothing thought the service WSDL is available.
Besides, we are capable of making a successful call to the service by using a client proxy. please refer to the below link.
[WCF: There was no endpoint listening at, that could accept the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018130/wcf-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-that-could-accept-the-message/54068160#54068160)
the above client proxy class is generated by adding service reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Here is a detailed exposition of WCFTestClient from Microsoft document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.